# Change camera orientation android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview

Hello Before starting this i would like to tell you that there are many topics with the similar title but my problem is different i am not able to change the orientation of the camera at all i have tried many things.

Following are my codes and its a live streaming project.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener,
    RtspClient.Callback,
    Session.Callback,
    SurfaceHolder.Callback,
    OnCheckedChangeListener {

public final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

private Button mButtonSave;
private Button mButtonVideo;
private ImageButton mButtonStart;
private ImageButton mButtonFlash;
private ImageButton mButtonCamera;
private ImageButton mButtonSettings;
private RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
private FrameLayout mLayoutVideoSettings;
private FrameLayout mLayoutServerSettings;
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private TextView mTextBitrate;
private EditText mEditTextURI;
private EditText mEditTextPassword;
private EditText mEditTextUsername;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private Session mSession;
private RtspClient mClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mButtonVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.video);
    mButtonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    mButtonStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.start);
    mButtonFlash = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flash);
    mButtonCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    mButtonSettings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mEditTextURI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uri);
    mEditTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mEditTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mTextBitrate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bitrate);
    mLayoutVideoSettings = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_layout);
    mLayoutServerSettings = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.server_layout);
    mRadioGroup =  (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    mRadioGroup.setOnClickListener(this);

    mButtonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonFlash.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonFlash.setTag("off");

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    if (mPrefs.getString("uri", null) != null) mLayoutServerSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mEditTextURI.setText(mPrefs.getString("uri", "default_stream"));
    mEditTextPassword.setText(mPrefs.getString("password", ""));
    mEditTextUsername.setText(mPrefs.getString("username", ""));

    // Configures the SessionBuilder
    mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
            .setContext(getApplicationContext())
            .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
            .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000,16000))
            .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
            .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
            .setPreviewOrientation(90)//I tried changing this value but nothing happened it works even if i comment this line.
            .setCallback(this)
            .build();

    // Configures the RTSP client
    mClient = new RtspClient();
    mClient.setSession(mSession);
    mClient.setCallback(this);
    Camera camera;


    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    selectQuality();

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    mLayoutVideoSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mLayoutServerSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    selectQuality();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.start:
            mLayoutServerSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toggleStream();
            break;
        case R.id.flash:
            if (mButtonFlash.getTag().equals("on")) {
                mButtonFlash.setTag("off");
                mButtonFlash.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on_holo_light);
            } else {
                mButtonFlash.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_off_holo_light);
                mButtonFlash.setTag("on");
            }
            mSession.toggleFlash();
            break;
        case R.id.camera:
            mSession.switchCamera();
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            if (mLayoutVideoSettings.getVisibility() == View.GONE &&
                    mLayoutServerSettings.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                mLayoutServerSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mLayoutServerSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mLayoutVideoSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.video:
            mRadioGroup.clearCheck();
            mLayoutServerSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mLayoutVideoSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.save:
            mLayoutServerSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mClient.release();
    mSession.release();
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
}

private void selectQuality() {
    int id = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton button = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
    if (button == null) return;

    String text = button.getText().toString();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)x(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    matcher.find();
    int width = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int height = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    int framerate = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
    int bitrate = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4))*1000;

    mSession.setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(width, height, framerate, bitrate));
    Toast.makeText(this, ((RadioButton)findViewById(id)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.d(TAG, "Selected resolution: "+width+"x"+height);
}

private void enableUI() {
    mButtonStart.setEnabled(true);
    mButtonCamera.setEnabled(true);
}

// Connects/disconnects to the RTSP server and starts/stops the stream
public void toggleStream() {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (!mClient.isStreaming()) {
        String ip,port,path;

        // We save the content user inputs in Shared Preferences
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("uri", mEditTextURI.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("password", mEditTextPassword.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("username", mEditTextUsername.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

        // We parse the URI written in the Editext
        Pattern uri = Pattern.compile("rtsp://(.+):(\\d*)/(.+)");
        Matcher m = uri.matcher(mEditTextURI.getText()); m.find();
        ip = m.group(1);
        port = m.group(2);
        path = m.group(3);

       // mClient.setCredentials(mEditTextUsername.getText().toString(), mEditTextPassword.getText().toString());
        mClient.setCredentials("umair", "123456");
        mClient.setServerAddress(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
        mClient.setStreamPath("/"+path);
        mClient.startStream();

    } else {
        // Stops the stream and disconnects from the RTSP server
        mClient.stopStream();
    }
}

private void logError(final String msg) {
    final String error = (msg == null) ? "Error unknown" : msg;
    // Displays a popup to report the eror to the user
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(msg).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {}
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onBitrateUpdate(long bitrate) {
    mTextBitrate.setText(""+bitrate/1000+" kbps");
}

@Override
public void onPreviewStarted() {
    if (mSession.getCamera() == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        mButtonFlash.setEnabled(true);
        mButtonFlash.setTag("off");
        mButtonFlash.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on_holo_light);
    }
    else {
        mButtonFlash.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSessionConfigured() {

}

@Override
public void onSessionStarted() {
    enableUI();
    mButtonStart.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_switch_video_active);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onSessionStopped() {
    enableUI();
    mButtonStart.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_switch_video);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onSessionError(int reason, int streamType, Exception e) {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    switch (reason) {
        case Session.ERROR_CAMERA_ALREADY_IN_USE:
            break;
        case Session.ERROR_CAMERA_HAS_NO_FLASH:
            mButtonFlash.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on_holo_light);
            mButtonFlash.setTag("off");
            break;
        case Session.ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE:
            break;
        case Session.ERROR_STORAGE_NOT_READY:
            break;
        case Session.ERROR_CONFIGURATION_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            VideoQuality quality = mSession.getVideoTrack().getVideoQuality();
            logError("The following settings are not supported on this phone: "+
                    quality.toString()+" "+
                    "("+e.getMessage()+")");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        case Session.ERROR_OTHER:
            break;
    }

    if (e != null) {
        logError(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRtspUpdate(int message, Exception e) {
    switch (message) {
        case RtspClient.ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED:
        case RtspClient.ERROR_WRONG_CREDENTIALS:
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            enableUI();
            logError(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
//tried adding the setPreiviewOrientation(90) here also but still nothing changed.
        mSession.startPreview();

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mClient.stopStream();
}
}
```

I have tried to change setPreviewOrientation also but still no changes check the codes i have commented whatever i tried please help me. [click here to see the API that i have used](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming)
[image: Check here to see how the orientation looks like]

Answer (score 1):

Add this method and call it where camera is open

```
 private void setUpCamera(Camera c) {
    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degree = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degree = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degree = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degree = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degree = 270;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        // frontFacing
        rotation = (info.orientation + degree) % 330;
        rotation = (360 - rotation) % 360;
    } else {
        // Back-facing
        rotation = (info.orientation - degree + 360) % 360;
    }
    c.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);
    Parameters params = c.getParameters();
    params.setRotation(rotation);
}

Add these in surfaceChanged method for image clarity and other.

Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
    for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
    {
        if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
            size = sizes.get(i);
    }
    parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
    parameters.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
    parameters.setExposureCompensation(0);
    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    parameters.setJpegQuality(100);

    try{
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
```